# Saving multi-dimensional array from post array into database using eloquent ORM

Tags: php, loops, laravel

i have multidimensional arrays in my post array which i would like to save into my database using laravel's eloquent ORM. This is the code:

```
$q = new Quiz;
$data = Input::get();

    for($i=0; $i < $query->no_questions; $i++)
    {
        $q->question = $data['question'][$i];
        $q->answers = json_encode($data['answers'][$i]);
        $q->correct_answer = $data['correctAnswer'][$i];
    }
$q->save();
```

However when i dump the contents of $q[] i see only one record which happens to be the last record in the array.  Is there a way for me to append each row to $q[] during each iteration?

eg.

```
$a[0] = array();
$a[1] = array();
$a[2] = array();
```

How do i append $a,$b and $c to $q[] in the for loop. The above is just an example of what i am trying to implement.

Please let me know if my post is not clear enough, thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the create a new object and save part into the loop. Otherwise you're always operating with the same model instance and only saving this one instance in the end.

This should work:

```
$data = Input::get();
for($i=0; $i < $query->no_questions; $i++)
{
    $q = new Quiz;
    $q->question = $data['question'][$i];
    $q->answers = json_encode($data['answers'][$i]);
    $q->correct_answer = $data['correctAnswer'][$i];
    $q->save();
}
```